# Is there a shorthand to avoid 'new char[...]' in String.Split?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

For all c#'s elegance over C++, this always seems clumsy to me (and the old school coder in me recoils at new-ing an array so gratuitously!)

Is there a more elegant syntax or an overloaded method I've missed?

E.g. `"a.b.c".Split(".".ToCharArray(),2);`

Comment: Please show us an example of what you mean

Comment: Use single quote 'c' - single quotes are for chars, double quotes for strings

Comment: Eh, `var result = myString.Split(',', '\r', '\n', ' ', '\t');` you don't have to put `new char[]` since it's declared as `String.Split(params char[]...`

Comment: Ah sorry you mean char arrays :D - yeah use an overload (variable params even)

Comment: You can omit the object type (char) e.g.: `whatever.Split(new[]{'x','y'}, StringSplitOptions.Whatever)`

Comment: `"or an overloaded method I've missed?"` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx -- Googled "MSDN String.Split"

Answer (score 2):

One of the overloads is `params char[]` so you can just pass in as many characters as you need without creating an array first.

```
"split me".Split('s','m'); // a random example
```

Reference to the [documentation for string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

#### Edit in Response to comment

> Although what about specifying the maximum number of elements to return? Is that not possible?

You could create your own extension that could do this so you have the best of both methods.

```
public static class CustomExtensions
{
    public static string[] Split(this string stringToSplit, int count, params char[] separator)
    {
        // todo: add some parameter validation checks (or not, your choice)
        return stringToSplit.Split(separator, count);
    }
}
```

And then call it

```
var result = "split me".Split(3, 's', 'm'); // a random example
```

Comment: I never knew there was a `params` version! Although what about specifying the maximum number of elements to return? Is that not possible?

Comment: @Mr.Boy - as a string array is returned the caller could then use the Linq extension `Take` to keep the top XXX number of elements if this was desirable.

Comment: @Mr.Boy - I deleted my earlier incorrect comment. If you want to specify the maximum number you have to create an array. `params` only works if it is the last parameter in the method and the other methods that do support `maximum number of substrings` do not support the `params` as an input for the chars array. So you are stuck between having to pick one or the other.

Comment: @Mr.Boy - I added a custom extension if you really wanted the best of both methods. Using that gets you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) page, there is no need to create an Array if you are using the chars as an argument

This is because the arguments are defined as `params char[]` which means that it takes an array, or just a list of arguments

```
string myString = "a,b;c";
string[] splittedString = myString.split(',', ';');
```

is essentially the same as

```
string myString = "a,b;c";
string[] splittedString = myString.split(new char[] { ',', ';' });
```

or even as

```
string myString = "a,b;c";
string[] splittedString = myString.split(new [] { ',', ';' });
```

Answer (score 0):

pass in the char to split by in single quotation marks (since Split() takes a param char[])

```
string str = "this is a sentence";
var s = str.Split(' '); // { "this", "is", "a", "sentence" }
var t = str.Split('s'); // { "thi", " i", " a ", "entence" }
```